# Testing if Point is located within a region

Tags: java

I am trying to create a code that will test if a point is within side a rectangle. and for some reason no matter the case it resolves false.

So give like a rectangle dimensions leftSide, topSide, recWidth, recHeight

I want to test if it's within a ptX and ptY so I have:

```
  if(ptX >= leftSide|| ptX > (lefSide + recWidth) || ptY < topSide|| ptY < (topSid+recHeight)) return false;
  else return true;

  //Sugggested code
  if(ptX >= leftSide && ptX < (leftSide + recWidth) && ptY > topSide && ptY < (topSid + recHeight) return true;

  //Rectange values: left, top,width, height: (-2.5, 2.5, 3.5, 7.5)
```

Do you know where I happen to mess up on. Specifically, it fails on pt(3,3). But it should return true on the very first statement correct? Becuase

Comment: In these kind of situations, I tend to write out the solution in long form, for example, `if x >= leftSide && x <= leftSide + width {...}` this gives a simple base line which easy to interrupt and debug if needed.  That might wrap itself up in a method or assign a flag a `true`/`false` value. From there, I'd then test `y` and with that information I could test both flags.  Once I have an understand of the long form, I might look at optimising the code if possible

Comment: So I was doing that just to be sure. Correct me if I am wrong the very first statement 3 >= -2.5 is true so should return true is why that statement is executing even though that should be false since it's out of the rectangle?

Comment: But `3 <= (-2.5 + 3.5)` (which equates to `3 <= 1`) is `false`.  You need to use `&&` not `||` to ensure the value falls between BOTH ranges

Comment: Is there another way I should be approaching this? Seems kinda cumbersome and slow. Also IDK if I would need a and statement because if the X value is out of the rectangle we shouldn't even really have to check the Y value because it's already out of the rectangle.

Comment: Well, the basic idea is to test if `x` is between `left` and `right` ranges and `y` is between `top` and `bottom` ranges, so there is some common functionality right there. The implementation of  `contains` in `java.awt.Rectangle` is about 17 lines :P

Comment: Right, so I'm testing if X is between in the box by left+width. So that statement is right. the ptX is testing if it's greater then the original position. And via Versa with my ptY's. So I dont get why my logic isn't working

Comment: To me, `ptX > (leftSide + recWidth)` doesn't make sense, because in your case, it's returning `true`, the problem is `true || false` is `true` ... so it's always going to trigger an issue, because in your code it's `true`, which equates to `true || true` which is `true` :P. I'd change it to `ptX >= leftSide && ptX < (leftSide + recWidth)` so that both the left and width check MUST return `true` before the condition is `true`.  A check of `true && false` will return `false`

Answer (score 0):

Considering that,
Left is indicating left most point
Top is indicating top most point
(Left, Top) gives Left Top corner
I think 3,3 does not fall in given rectangle i have adjusted inputs please verify.
Following program will return correct output :

```
double ptX = 3;
    double ptY = 3;
    double leftSide = -2.5;
    double topSide = 2.5;
    double height = 3.5;
    double width = 7.5;
    if(ptX >= leftSide && ptX <= leftSide+width && ptY <= topSide  && ptY > topSide - height) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, lets break this down a little, let's start with...

```
double leftSide = -2.5;
double recWidth = 3.5;

double topSide = 2.5;
double recHeight = 7.5;

double ptX = 3;
double ptY = 3;

System.out.println(ptX >= leftSide || ptX > (leftSide + recWidth));
System.out.println(ptX >= leftSide);
System.out.println(ptX > (leftSide + recWidth));
```

- `ptX >= leftSide` is `true`, okay
- `ptX > (leftSide + recWidth)` is also `true`, okay

But, that makes `ptX >= leftSide || ptX > (leftSide + recWidth)` `true` as well ... that's not what we want.

Besides, `true || false` is `true` so even if one of those previous conditions was `false`, the comparison would return `true` ... not pretty.

A better solution would be to check if the value is "between" those two values.

So, instead we could say...

- `ptX >= leftSide` which is `true`
- `ptX < (leftSide + recWidth)` which is `false`

Then we should use `&&` (because they both need to be `true` to be `true`)

`ptX >= leftSide && ptX < (leftSide + recWidth)` which returns `false! Which is the answer we're actual after!

Now, basically, we need to do the same for the `y` position and then `&&` those two results together, because unless both a `true`, it's not within the bounds of the rectangle

Comment: Ok intresting, I updated my code with what I think you suggested (I edited my orignal post with what I think you meant). It actually works for all of my points I want to print. However, on a testing driver, it fails on point (3.2,2.4) with a different rectangle.

Comment: @John Well, I can't say as to the values of the other rectangle as I have no context

Comment: Figured it out. Thanks for your help!